# MySQL 5.6.10 via apt-get

Tags: mysql, apt-get, aptitude

MySQL 5.6.10 is *Generally Available* now. If I try to upgrade it however says that I am already at the newest version, even though the installed version is 5.5.29. I am on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get install --upgrade mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

I ran `sudo apt-get update` beforehand.

Did anyone manage to install MySQL 5.6 via aptitude yet?

Comment: Why would you close this question?

Comment: build it from source!

Comment: It's probably closed because it's more suitable at superuser or other such sites.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do this via aptitude but you can try to compile newest version from source.

- **Install libaio**

> ```
> $ cd /opt
> $ wget http://www.morphisms.net/~wkj/download/libaio.tbz
> $ bunzip2 libaio.tbz
> $ tar xf libaio.tar
> ```

- **Download MySQL 5.6.10**

> ```
> $ wget http://www.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.10.tar.gz/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/
> $ tar xzf mysql-5.6.10.tar.gz
> $ cd mysql-5.6.10
> ```

- **Configure and compile MySQL**

> ```
> $ PATH=$PATH:/opt/bison/bin   #bison binary should be in your path
>
> $ cmake . -DWITH_ARCHIVE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 -DWITH_FEDERATED_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 
> -DWITH_BLACKHOLE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/opt/mysql-5.6.10/data/ 
> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/mysql-5.6.10 -DCURSES_LIBRARY=/opt/ncurses/lib/libncurses.a 
> -DCURSES_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/ncurses/include/ -DHAVE_LIBAIO_H=/opt/libaio/include/ 
>  -DINSTALL_LAYOUT=STANDALONE -DENABLED_PROFILING=ON 
> -DMYSQL_MAINTAINER_MODE=OFF -DWITH_DEBUG=OFF -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 
> -DENABLED_LOCAL_INFILE=TRUE -DWITH_ZLIB=bundled
>
> $ make
> ```

**Set correct system locations!**

- **Install**

> make install

It is working for me. Via: http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/installation/download_configure_compile_and_install_mysql_56.php

Comment: Use `wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.15.tar.gz` to get the latest version of source (as of today 5.6.15)